# Text adventure is only reading the first line of a description rather than the whole thing

Tags: c++

I'm building a text adventure program and can't figure out why its only reading out the first line of the rooms.txt file rather than the whole desc. I included my whole program and the txt file that I'm not allowed to modify.

For example it should read out : You are standing in front of the gate to a large mysterious mansion.
The thick nightime fog obsures the building but you can make out a few
lights coming from the building. Someone is awake. The gate’s rusted lock
seems ready to fall off. Maybe if you bashed the gate hard enough, you
could get through, or you could try to climb over the gate. Would you like
to CLIMB or BASH the gate?

rather than just:You are standing in front of the gate to a large mysterious mansion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

class Option {
  public: string keyword;
  string stat;
  string pass_text;
  string fail_text;
  int pass_exit;
  int fail_exit;
  int damage;
};

class Room {
  public: int number;
  string description;
  vector < Option > options;
};

class World {
  public: vector < Room > rooms;
  int current_room;

  Room find_room(int room_number) {
    for (Room & room: rooms) {
      if (room.number == room_number) {
        return room;
      }
    }
    Room empty_room;
    empty_room.number = -1;
    return empty_room;
  }

  void read_rooms(const string & filename) {
    ifstream file(filename);
    string line;
    Room current_room;

    while (getline(file, line)) {
      stringstream ss(line);
      string word;
      ss >> word;

      if (word == "Room:") {
        if (current_room.number != -1) {
          rooms.push_back(current_room);
        }
        ss >> current_room.number;
        current_room.options.clear();
      } else if (word == "Desc:") {
        getline(ss, current_room.description, '\n');
      } else if (word == "Option:") {
        Option option;
        ss >> option.keyword;
        current_room.options.push_back(option);
      } else if (word == "Stat:") {
        ss >> current_room.options.back().stat;
      } else if (word == "Pass:") {
        getline(ss, current_room.options.back().pass_text, '\n');
      } else if (word == "Pexit:") {
        ss >> current_room.options.back().pass_exit;
      } else if (word == "Fail:") {
        getline(ss, current_room.options.back().fail_text, '\n');
      } else if (word == "Fexit:") {
        ss >> current_room.options.back().fail_exit;
      } else if (word == "Damage:") {
        string dice_str;
        ss >> dice_str;
        current_room.options.back().damage = stoi(dice_str.substr(2));
      }
    }
    rooms.push_back(current_room);
    file.close();
  }

  void display_room() {
    Room room = find_room(current_room);
    cout << room.description << endl;

    for (Option & option: room.options) {
      cout << option.keyword << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  int roll_dice(int sides) {
    return rand() % sides + 1;
  }

  bool handle_input(string input, int & strength, int & dexterity,
    int & intelligence, int & charisma, int & current_health) {
    Room room = find_room(current_room);

    for (Option & option: room.options) {
      if (input == option.keyword) {
        bool success;
        int stat_value;

        if (option.stat == "str") {
          stat_value = strength;
        } else if (option.stat == "dex") {
          stat_value = dexterity;
        } else if (option.stat == "int") {
          stat_value = intelligence;
        } else if (option.stat == "cha") {
          stat_value = charisma;
        } else {
          stat_value = -1;
        }

        if (stat_value != -1) {
          success = roll_dice(20) + stat_value >= 10;
        } else {
          success = true;
        }

        if (success) {
          cout << option.pass_text << endl;
          current_room = option.pass_exit;
        } else {
          cout << option.fail_text << endl;
          current_health -= roll_dice(option.damage);
          cout << "You have " << current_health << " health remaining." <<
            endl;
          current_room = option.fail_exit;
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
};

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));

  int strength = rand() % 16 + 3;
  int dexterity = rand() % 16 + 3;
  int intelligence = rand() % 16 + 3;
  int charisma = rand() % 16 + 3;
  int max_health = rand() % 6 + 11;
  int current_health = max_health;

  cout << "Strength: " << strength << endl;
  cout << "Dexterity: " << dexterity << endl;
  cout << "Intelligence: " << intelligence << endl;
  cout << "Charisma: " << charisma << endl;
  cout << "Max Health: " << max_health << endl;
  cout << "Current Health: " << current_health << endl;

  string input;
  cout << "Type 'Begin' to start, or anything else to quit: ";
  getline(cin, input);

  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    input[i] = tolower(input[i]);
  }

  if (input != "begin") {
    cout << "Thank you for playing." << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  World world;
  world.read_rooms("rooms.txt");
  world.current_room = 1;

  while (world.current_room != 9999) {
    world.display_room();
    cout << "What do you want to do? ";
    getline(cin, input);
    transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), ::tolower);

    if (!world.handle_input(input, strength, dexterity, intelligence, charisma, current_health)) {
      cout << "Invalid input, please try again." << endl;
    }
  }

  cout << "Thank you for playing." << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

rooms.txt

```
Room: 1
Desc: You are standing in front of the gate to a large mysterious mansion.
The thick nightime fog obsures the building but you can make out a few
lights coming from the building. Someone is awake. The gate’s rusted lock
seems ready to fall off. Maybe if you bashed the gate hard enough, you
could get through, or you could try to climb over the gate. Would you like
to CLIMB or BASH the gate?
Option: climb
Stat: dex
Pass: You carefully climb over the old rusted gate. You land safely on
your feet inside the grounds of the mysterious mansion.
Pexit: 2
Fail: As you make your way over the rusted gate, the finial you are using
for support snaps and you land hard on the ground below. You take DMG
damage and are a little shaken. Nevertheless, you have made it inside the
grounds of the mysterious mansion.
Fexit: 2
Damage: 1d4
Option: bash
Stat: str
Pass: You put all your weight into a massive assault on the gate. As you
suspected, the lock was not up to the challenge and gave way easily. You
hear a large thud as the gate crashes open. You have made it inside the
grounds of the mysterious mansion.
Pexit: 3
Fail: You put all your weight into a massive assault on the gate. At
first, the lock resists your attack, and the collision with the gate bites
into your shoulder. You take DMG damage. After a moment's hesitation, the
lock gives, and the gate swings open with a thud. You have made it inside
the grounds of the mysterious mansion.
Fexit: 3
Damage: 1d4
Room: 2
Desc: You have made it onto the grounds of the mysterious mansion. A long
driveway stretches before you. It leads to the an ornate main entry
portico old barely visible in the distance. To your left you hear the
sounds of flowing water coming from behind a hedge. To your right you
think you see a swing rocking back and forth suspended from a large oak
tree. Would you like to go FORWARD, LEFT, or RIGHT?
Option: forward
Stat: none
Pass: With you heart ponding you boldly start to make your way towards the
front entrance of the mansion.
Pexit: 4
Option: left
Stat: none
Pass: Curious as to what that sound could be you make your way to the left
around the hedge.
Pexit: 5
Option: right
Stat: none
Pass: As you begin to approach the old oak tree, the thought occurs to you
that there isn't enough breeze in the air to push the heavy tire swing.
Pexit: 6
Room: 3
Desc: You have made it onto the grounds of the mysterious mansion. A long
driveway stretches before you. It leads to the an ornate main entry
portico old barely visible in the distance. To your left you hear the
sounds of flowing water coming from behind a hedge. To your right the loud
crash of the gate seems to have drawn some attention. A shadow, moving in
the distance, seems to be getting larger. Would you like to STAND your
ground, RUN up the driveway, or HIDE behind the hedge.
Option: stand
Stat: none
Pass: You hold your ground and wait as the figure aproaches. A sleepy eyed
dog emerges from the darkness and stares at you. Find out what happens
next whaen the full game launches. Thank you for playing the demo.
Pexit: 9999
Option: run
Stat: dex
Pass: As the gate disapears rapidly into the fog you catch a glimpse of a
large dog. It does not seem to have noticed you.
Pexit: 4
Fail: It's too late, the figure emerges from the darkness and blocks your
path. A sleepy eyed dog stares at you apearantly waiting for something.
Find out what happens next whaen the full game launches. Thank you for
playing the demo.
Fexit: 9999
Option: hide
Stat: dex
Pass: That was close! You swiftly dodge behind the hedge before a large
dog emerges from the dark onto the path you just left.
Pexit: 5
Fail: It's too late, the figure emerges from the darkness and blocks your
path. A sleepy eyed dog stares at you apearantly waiting for something.
Find out what happens next whaen the full game launches. Thank you for
playing the demo.
Fexit: 9999
Room: 4
Desc: Inside the portico you can see the ornate front door of the mansion
looming before you. A large brass knocker dares you to alert the occupants
to your presance. To the left you can see a cavernous garage which has
been left open. Do you want to attempt to OPEN the door, KNOCK on the
door, or enter the GARAGE?
Option: open
Stat: none
Pass: That's all for now. Thank you for playing the demo.
Pexit: 9999
Option: knock
Stat: none
Pass: That's all for now. Thank you for playing the demo.
Pexit: 9999
Option: garage
Stat: none
Pass: That's all for now. Thank you for playing the demo.
Pexit: 9999
Room: 5
Desc: You are in a small garden walled on all sides by a neatly trimmed
hedge. In the center is a beautiful fairy tending a stone garden at her
feet. A constant flow of water pours from her pitcher onto the
meticulously carved stone flowers and into a pool surrounding the statue.
Across the way you can make out a gap in the hedge. Would you like to
INVESTIGATE the statue or go through the GAP in the hedge?
Option: investigate
Stat: none
Pass: That's all for now. Thank you for playing the demo.
Pexit: 9999
Option: gap
Stat: none
Pass: That's all for now. Thank you for playing the demo.
Pexit: 9999
Room: 6
Desc: The tree seems to have stood sentinal on this spot since before time
began. You feel a strong presence from its ancient root. As stand
transfixed by the oscillating tire swing, you begin to hear a faint
whisper. Beyond it you can see the dim light of a fire in the distance. Go
PAST the swing toward the fire, go BACK to the path, STAND and listing to
the whisper.
Option: past
Stat: none
Pass: That's all for now. Thank you for playing the demo.
Pexit: 9999
Option: back
Stat: none
Pass: You decide not to meddel with such ancient forces. You turn around
and head back to the path.
Pexit: 2
Option: stand
Stat: none
Pass: That's all for now. Thank you for playing the demo.
Pexit: 9999
```

I tried changing the read_rooms function in the World class. I replaced the line getline (ss, current_room.description, '\n'); with getline (ss, current_room.description); but that didn't work

Answer (score 3):

```
while (getline(file, line)) {
  stringstream ss(line);
  string word;
  ss >> word;

  if (word == "Room:") {
    ....
  } else if (word == "Desc:") {
    getline(ss, current_room.description, '\n');
  } else if (word == "Option:") {
```

You're reading in from `file` one line at a time, and storing each line in a string `line`.  The line is `Desc: You are standing in front of the gate to a large mysterious mansion.`.  That's the whole line.  That starts with `Desc:` , so that is stored into the room description.

Then the `while` loop reads in the next line. `The thick nightime fog obsures the building but you can make out a few` This does not start with `Desc:`, so your code skips it.

Instead of reading in line by line, you'll have to build some sort of smarter state machine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is more complicated then it seems to be.

It is all about parsing your text file and extract the keywords and the corresponding attributes.

But why is it that complicated? Because you have structured data, but no structure in your text file. If you would have a JSON, XML or simply a CSV file, then life would be very simple.

Even if you would not have text attributes over multiple lines, then parsing would be simple, because then you would have a clear delimiter at the end of a keyword/attribute pair.

I will show you some examples on what I mean.

Let us look at a structure having no newlines in text attributes. For long text, the editor or the terminal will break the lines for you.

```
Keyword1: Very long text attribute
Keyword2: Very long text attribute
Keyword3: Very long text attribute
```

Even, if the Editor or the terminal would break the lines for you, from C++ point of view, an pair of keyword/attribute would be still in one line. Then you could simply read a line and then split it after the first colon ':'. That would be very simple.

Same for the CSV by using for example < '|' as delimiter

```
Keyword1|Very long text attribute|Keyword2|Very long text attribute|Keyword3|Very long text attribute
```

That can be easily parsed with many existing CSV-read algorithms.

But it seems, like we need to go the heavy way.

There are of course many different potential solutions.

- using lex/yacc or flex/bison or boost spirit
- Reading all text into one string and then find positions of keywords and attributes. Use the `std::string`s `find` and `substr` functions.
- Using mini state machine with look ahead analysis
- and many more . . .

I will show an example with the mini state machine. The main problem is that we will read character by character and that we will know the end of a key/attribute pair only after we have read the next key word. But then we have already consume/read the next keyword, and we cannot evaluate it again.

Example:

```
Keyword1: attribute1 part1
attribute1 part2
Keyword2: attribute2 part1
attribute2 part2
Keyword3: attribute3 part1
attribute3 part2
```

So, we read the first keyword. Fine. Then we read attribute text and more text. At some point we have read keyword 2. Then we are finished with the first keyword/attribute pair. But, we have read keyword 2 already, we extracted it from the stream. So, we need to handle that. We could remember the new key word and continue, or set back the file read pointer and read again.

The below example uses the file read pointer setting.

I also did some general refactoring.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

struct Option {
    std::string keyword{};
    std::string stat{};
    std::string passText{};
    std::string failText{};
    int passExit{};
    int failExit{};
    int damage{};
};

struct Room {
    int number{-1};
    std::string description{};
    std::vector<Option> options{};
};

class World {
    std::vector<Room> rooms{};
public:
    int currentRoom{};

    void readRooms(const std::string& fileName);
    void displayRoom();
    bool handleInput(const std::string& input, const int strength, const int dexterity, const int intelligence, const int charisma, int& current_health);
};

int randomNumber(const int low, const int high) {
    static std::mt19937 randomGenerator{}; // Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with standard
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(low, high);
    return distribution(randomGenerator);
}
void World::displayRoom() {
    std::cout << rooms[currentRoom].description << "\n\nOptions: \t";
    for (const Option& option : rooms[currentRoom].options) {
        std::cout << option.keyword << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}


const std::vector<std::string> KeyWords{"Room: ", "Desc: ", "Option: ", "Stat: ", "Pass: ", "Pexit: ", "Fail: ", "Fexit: ", "Damage: "};

// Check, if a line begins with a keyword from above vector
std::string lineBeginsWithKeyWord(const std::string& line) {
    std::string result{};
    // Compare the beginning of the line with all keywords
    for (const std::string s : KeyWords)
        if (line.substr(0, s.length()) == s) {
            result = s;
            break;
        }
    return result;
}

std::istream& readKeyWordAndAttribute(std::istream& is, std::string& keyWord, std::string& attribute) {
    bool readingDone{};                     // Indicator, if there is still text to read
    bool waitForKeyWord{true};              // Are we waiting for a key word. At the beginning, we wait for it
    keyWord.clear();                        // Reset / clear the keyword
    attribute.clear();                      // Reset / clear the keyword
    std::vector<std::string> linePart{};    // Here we collect parts of a multi-line string

    // As long as there is something to read
    while (not readingDone) {

        // Remember the current position in the file
        std::istream::pos_type positionBeforeReadingLine = is.tellg();

        // Now read a line, and check, if that was OK. We can hit EOL here
        if (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line)) {
    
            // We have 2 states. Either, we wait for the next keyword or we read the attribute of the keyword
            if (waitForKeyWord) {

                // Check, if the line or a part of the line, begins with a keyword.
                // If so, then store it (else, it will be empty)
                keyWord = lineBeginsWithKeyWord(line);

                // Did we read a keyword
                if (not keyWord.empty()) {

                    // Now set the file position pointer to after the keyword
                    is.seekg(positionBeforeReadingLine + static_cast<std::istream::pos_type>(keyWord.length()));

                    // We have read the keyword, so, next time we will read the attribute
                    // Not, we are still on the same line
                    waitForKeyWord = false;
                    // Reset / clear the collector for line parts in case of attributes with multiple line
                    linePart.clear();
                }
            }
            else {
                // We check the next line or line part. We look ahead
                if (lineBeginsWithKeyWord(line).empty()) {

                    // If there was no keyword in this line, then store the line
                    linePart.push_back(line);
                }
                else {
                    // If there was a keyword in this line, then we read to far. We are
                    // now alread in the next line with a new keyword. Hence, ew reset the file read pointer 
                    // to the start of the line, taht we have just read
                    is.seekg(positionBeforeReadingLine);

                    // Obviously, we have now read the keyword and the attribute
                    readingDone = true;

                    // We need to handle multiple attribute lines. This, because std::getline 
                    // will not add '\n's at the ned of a line. So, if we have more then one line
                    if (linePart.size() > 1) {
                        // Then add a newline at the end of each line
                        for (std::string& s : linePart)
                            s += '\n';
                    }
                    // Now build the attribute from all line parts
                    for (const std::string& s : linePart)
                        attribute += s;
                }
            }
        } // In case of eof or other istream error
        else readingDone = true;
    }
    return is;
}

void World::readRooms(const std::string& fileName) {
    if (std::ifstream ifs{ fileName }; ifs) {
        
        std::string keyWord{};
        std::string attribute{};

        while (readKeyWordAndAttribute(ifs, keyWord, attribute)) {
            if (keyWord == KeyWords[0]) { // Room
                rooms.push_back({});
                rooms.back().number = std::stoi(attribute);
            }
            else if (keyWord == KeyWords[1]) { // Desc
                rooms.back().description = attribute;
            }
            else if (keyWord == KeyWords[2]) { // Option
                rooms.back().options.push_back({});
                rooms.back().options.back().keyword = attribute;
            }
            else if (keyWord == KeyWords[3]) { // Stat
                rooms.back().options.back().stat = attribute;
            }
            else if (keyWord == KeyWords[4]) { // Pass
                rooms.back().options.back().passText = attribute;
            }
            else if (keyWord == KeyWords[5]) { // Pexit
                rooms.back().options.back().passExit = std::stoi(attribute);
            }
            else if (keyWord == KeyWords[6]) { // Fail
                rooms.back().options.back().failText = attribute;
            }
            else if (keyWord == KeyWords[7]) { // Fexit
                rooms.back().options.back().failExit = std::stoi(attribute);
            }
            else if (keyWord == KeyWords[8]) { // Damage
                rooms.back().options.back().damage = std::stoi(attribute.substr(2));
            }
            else {
                // nothing
            }
        }
    }
    else std::cout << "\nError: Could not open file '" << fileName << "'\n\n";
}

bool World::handleInput(const std::string& input, const int strength, const int dexterity, const int intelligence, const int charisma, int& current_health) {

    if (currentRoom < 0 or currentRoom >= rooms.size())
        currentRoom = 0;
    for (const Option& option : rooms[currentRoom].options) {

        if (input == option.keyword) {

            bool success{};
            int statValue{};

            if (option.stat == "str") {
                statValue = strength;
            }
            else if (option.stat == "dex") {
                statValue = dexterity;
            }
            else if (option.stat == "int") {
                statValue = intelligence;
            }
            else if (option.stat == "cha") {
                statValue = charisma;
            }
            else {
                statValue = -1;
            }

            if (statValue != -1) {
                success = randomNumber(1,20) + statValue >= 10;
            }
            else {
                success = true;
            }
            if (success) {
                std::cout << option.passText << '\n';
                currentRoom = option.passExit;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << option.failText << '\n';
                current_health -= randomNumber(1,option.damage);
                std::cout << "You have " << current_health << " health remaining.\n";
                currentRoom = option.failExit;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {

    World world{};

    int strength = randomNumber(0,15) + 3;
    int dexterity = randomNumber(0, 15) + 3;
    int intelligence = randomNumber(0, 15) + 3;
    int charisma = randomNumber(0, 15) + 3;
    int max_health = randomNumber(0, 5) + 11;

    int current_health = max_health;

    std::cout << "Strength:\t " << strength << "\nDexterity:\t " << dexterity << "\nIntelligence:\t " << intelligence 
        << "\nCharisma:\t " << charisma << "\nMax Health:\t " << max_health << "\nCurrent Health:\t " << current_health 
        << "\n\nType 'Begin' to start, or anything else to quit: ";

    std::string input; getline(std::cin, input); std::cout << "\n\n";
        for (char& c : input) c = std::tolower(c);

    if (input != "begin") {
        std::cout << "\nExiting . . .\nThank you for playing.\n\n";
    }
    else {

        world.readRooms("rooms.txt");

        while (world.currentRoom != 9999) {
            world.displayRoom();
            std::cout << "\nWhat do you want to do? ";
            std::getline(std::cin, input); std::cout << "\n\n";
            for (char& c : input) c = std::tolower(c);

            if (!world.handleInput(input, strength, dexterity, intelligence, charisma, current_health)) {
                std::cout << "\nError: Invalid input, please try again.\n\n";
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\nThank you for playing.\n\n";
}
```